# Linq to Sql: Optimizing lamba expression - clean code

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have this expression, which generates single query to the database:

```
db = new MyDataContext();
var productInCity = db.Products
                         .Where(n => n.id == 2)
                         .Select(k => new ProductInCityDto()
                         {
                              ProductName = k.ProductName,
                              CityName = k.Store.City.Name,
                              CountryName = k.Store.City.Country.Name
                              .
                              .
                              . 
                         })
                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

I want to make this code cleaner, by putting the mapping in a function, extension method or in the object's constructor, something like this:

```
db = new MyDataContext();
var productInCity = db.Products
                        .Where(n => n.id == 2)
                        .Select(k => new ProductInCityDto(k))
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

But, in this case, multiple queries to the DB are generated (I use LinqToSql Profiler).

Is there a way to isolate the mapping (Select statement) in order to achieve better code readability?

Comment: Does your DataContext use LazyLoading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YES, if you look at the actual signature of the Select extension method on IQueryable you will find that it does not take a function but an Expression>.

So, just do that...

```
Expression<Func<Product, ProductInCityDto>> MyMappingExpression
{
    get
    {
        return product => new ProductInCityDto
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

and then

```
db = new MyDataContext();
            var productInCity = db.Products.Where(n => n.id == 2)
                .Select(MyMappingExpression)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you need to use MyMappingExpression in process you will likely want to convert it to a

```
Func<Product, ProductInCityDto>
```

by calling the Expression.Compile() method.

Comment: I only changed 

`Expression<Func<ProductInCityDto, Product>> MyMappingExpression`

into 

`Expression<Func<Product, ProductInCityDto>> MyMappingExpression`

Comment: @AleksandarMafilovski Sorry about the mistake. Fixed.

Comment: I have another question connected to this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025047/linq-to-sql-nested-expression/15025792

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating mappings by hand, you may use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/). But if you do not want to create the mapping using a third party tool just change the query to the following;

```
var productInCity = new ProductInCity(
                   db.Products.Include("Store").SingleOrDefault(n => n.id == 2));
```