# Linq To Sql Nested Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am using this expression to get all products:

```
Expression<Func<Product, ProductInCityDto>> GetAllProducts
{
    get
    {
        return product => new ProductInCityDto
        {
             ProductName = product.ProductName,
             CityName = product.Store.City.Name,
             CountryName = product.Store.City.Country.Name,
             ProductAvgPrice =  CalculateAvg(product)
             . 
             . 
             .  
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the function CalculateAvg to calculate the product's average price. The calculation is in separated function because I'm using this code in several places.
However, this approach causes multiple calls to the database. 
Is it possible to replace the function CalculateAvg with Linq Expression, in order to have only one call to the DB?

Edit:

The function CalculateAvg looks something like this:

```
public static decimal CalculateAvg(object tempObj)
{
   Product obj = tempObj as Product; 
   return Convert.ToDecimal
          (obj.Sales.Where(n => n.type != 1)
                 .Average(n=>n.Price)
          );
}
```

Comment: how does `CalculateAvg` look? please show code

Comment: Try returning `IQuerable<decimal>` instead (remove the `Convert.ToDecimal`)

Comment: Could post some more code, how does your expression look like? Are you sure the multiple calls are because of that function, not because the rest of your expression might do something off?

Comment: @Magnus Average returns double, not IQueryable<decimal>

Comment: @Bjorn I am sure, I am using Linq to Sql profiler, and I have even isolated only this code, and the result is same

Comment: Are you using the Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL?

Comment: @NicholasButler Linq 2 Sql

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would refactor your function into a extension method and remove the conversion to isolate some possibilities. Remember that you have to place an extension method in a static class.

```
public static double CalculateAvg(this Product product)
{
   return product.Sales.Where(n => n.type != 1).Average(n=>n.Price);
}
```

If this would still cause multiple round trips, please post the query you see in the profiler so we can work from that.

Comment: It doesn't work. The same thing happens. The sql query that is generated is simple, and is executed multiple times (once per every product, with different id).

Comment: And when you would return just a '0' (zero) in the CalculateAvg-function the round trips do not occur is that correct?

Comment: The round trips do not occur in that case

Answer (score 0):

The difficult part of this isn't the conversion to the Linq expression. The difficult part is the invoking of the Expression. Which is hard. But worst of all, it isn't typesafe, and involves something akin to reflection.

The actual magic part is IQueryable.Provider.Execute(Expression)..

You can certainly try this...but it is by no means tested. Not to mention, pretty fugly.

```
Expression<Func<Product, ProductInCityDto>> GetAllProducts
{
    get
    {
        return product => new ProductInCityDto
        {
             ProductName = product.ProductName,
             CityName = product.Store.City.Name,
             CountryName = product.Store.City.Country.Name,
             //Bit of a hack to coerce the Provider out...
             ProductAvgPrice = product.Sales
                    .AsQueryable.Provider
                    .Execute<double>(CalculateAvg(product), Expression.Constant(product, typeof (Product)) ),
             . 
             . 
             .  
        }
    }
}

public Expression<Func<Product, double>> CalculateAvg()
{
    return product => product.Sales.Where(n => n.type != 1).Average(n=>n.Price);
}
```